# NSString intValue returns 0 if I substring it from the beginning of a string taken from a byte buffer

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
NSString *counter = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer+1 length:11 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //@"003{of}004"
NSString *c1Str = [counter substringToIndex:4];
NSString *c2Str = [counter substringFromIndex:8];

int c1Int = [c1Str intValue];
int c2Int = [c2Str intValue];

NSLog(@"c1Str=%@; c2Str=%@; c1Int=%i; c2Int=%i", c1Str, c2Str, c1Int, c2Int);

//The output is
//c1Str=003; c2Str=004; c1Int=0; c2Int=4
```

So I get 0 (zero) for c1Int while c2Int is fine.
Absolutely the same result is if I use:

```
NSArray *counterValues = [counter componentsSeparatedByString:@"{of}"];
int c1Int = [[counterValues objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int c2Int = [[[counterValues objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
```

I get the counter from a byte buffer that I read from NSInputStream. Defining *counter directly as @"003{of}004" works properly.

Why is it so? What is so special in *c1Str that intValue treats it as zero? How can I combat it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
The question is not actual anymore for me. But it may be useful for others.
I couldn't understand and resolve my task in terms as it was set. I had to re-think and change my workflow.

I'd like to give more details of where the problem roots from. 
I transfer png files via network and receive the data on the ios. The idea was to send a byte array read from a file, with leading special tags been attached to notify that the file is coming and what the counter is.

So the structure sent would look like:
[6][003{of}004][file data package], where "[" and "]" brackets are only for you here to understand the structure.

As I mentioned the data comes to NSInputStream, and I can catch [6], and I can catch [003{of}004], and I can catch the rest of the data. NSLog shows it clearly. But something is really odd with the counter string, i would say something with the beginning of the string is odd.

First of all, yes, if I try to retrieve the parts by substring'ing them then I have to use strange indexes.

intValue returns 0 whatever method I use to retrieve 003 and 004, with 004 been treated always correctly as expected!

If someone can give an explanation of why this may happen (and ideally a working solution) that would be definitely useful and much appreciated.

Thanks a lot to all who responded.

P.S. I work around this by sending the counter separately as a string, with different notify tag been attached in the beginning. As I don't need a fixed length of the counter now, my values coming are just numbers as is: 3{of}4, or 121{of}784 etc. (no leading zeros)

Comment: Just put an NSLog for counter also.. see what will print..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your `c1Str` print as `003` in log.

Change

```
[counter substringToIndex:4];
```

to

```
[counter substringToIndex:3];
```

if your `counter` string is `003{of}004`

Comment: The indexes are correct. If I define NSString *counter = @"003{of}004" then the values I get are 3 and 4. And also as described, I tried the other method to retrieve the parts. And also the logs are showing the correct strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong output, if your string is @"003{of}004" you have to use another indexes!

```
NSString *c1Str = [counter substringToIndex:3];
NSString *c2Str = [counter substringFromIndex:7];
```

Comment: The indexes are correct. If I define NSString *counter = @"003{of}004" then the values I get are 3 and 4. And also as described, I tried the other method to retrieve the parts. And also the logs are showing the correct strings.

Comment: I tried your code with substrings and i got the strings like "003{" and "04", and code with components works fine. May be problem in counter string?